# How to generate next the available dot decimal notation number in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue tracking sheet where each issue is associated with a base Requirement_Name and assigned an Issue_ID using dot decimal notation. The first 3 digits if the Issue_ID identify the Requirement_Name and the fourth number is an incrementing issue number for the specified Requirement_Name.

Due to the nature of sheets allowing sorting and filtering, the Issue_IDs are rarely in order or visible in the Issue sheet. When trying to manually create a new Issue_ID for a Requirement_Name, we are finding that we often create duplicate Issue_IDs. I have added conditional formatting to highlight Issue_IDs that are duplicates. However this still requires a certain amount of "guessing" to add the next available Issue_ID.

I am using Data validation on the *Issue sheet* to choose a Requirement_Name from the *Requirement sheet* and would like to be able to auto generate the next available Issue_ID for the chosen Requirement.

I am fairly new to GAS but do have some programming experience. I have found a way to return the MAX number from a column but cannot find a way to apply this same logic to find the MAX of last number of the Issue_ID based on the chosen Requirement_Name, and then generate the next number.

Edit: Here is a [link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6yU9vIc36mXoUi3l6rja_iEi19RXoho_LnPqGhmIQ4/edit?usp=sharing/) I am working on.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

## Requirement Sheet

| Requirement_ID | Requirement_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.1 | Requirement 1 |
| 1.2.1 | Requirement 2 |

## Issue Sheet

| Requirement_Name | Issue_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Requirement 1 | 1.1.1.1 |
| Requirement 2 | 1.2.1.1 |
| Requirement 1 | 1.1.1.3 |
| Requirement 1 | 1.1.1.4 |
| Requirement 1 | 1.1.1.2 |
| Requirement 2 | 1.2.1.2 |

Comment: if you will share a link to a sample spreadsheet (it need only contain exactly what you have shown above), I will leave on on-sheet formula-based solution for you. Just be sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone > Editor." Then I will explain the solution here for future site visitors.

Comment: @ErikTyler Link added to OP. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6yU9vIc36mXoUi3l6rja_iEi19RXoho_LnPqGhmIQ4/edit?usp=sharing) it is as well.

Comment: There is no sample data in the Issues sheet. Please fill in five sample rows in 'Issues' A where "Requirement_Name" from your post above would go, as well as manually filling in what you expect the result to be in Column B. I will then use that to work out the solution in B.

Comment: Also, please explain how the value of 1.0.0.1 was decided in Issues!B2. According to the logic in your post, A2 would have to have said "General xStore" (from 'Requirements' sheet).

Comment: I have added some sample data as it might appear in a sheet after resorting. The previous Issue_ID of 1.0.0.1 was the result of some testing I did. Note that typically the sheet would be filtered to show only Priority(Column H)=1.Current, but I have not applied any filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in B1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"ID #",IF(A:A="",,VLOOKUP(A:A,{Requirement!B:B,Requirement!A:A},2,FALSE)&"."&COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,F:F,"<="&F:F))))`

This one formula generates the heading as well as all of the column results, which will expand as more data is added to Column A.

The formula is specific to the fact that you are using filters.

**How It Works**

`=ArrayFormula(...)`

This indicates that an entire range will be processed rather than a single cell.

`IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"ID #", ... )`

This generated the header in Row 1.

`IF(A:A="",, ... )`

This assures than any empty rows in Column A remain empty in Column B.

`VLOOKUP(A:A,{Requirement!B:B,Requirement!A:A},2,FALSE)`

This looks up the Requirement from Column A in a virtual array formed from swapped rows A and B from the 'Requirement' sheet and returns the root ID number.

`&"."`

This appends a dot to the above.

`&COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,F:F,"<="&F:F)`

This appends a number based on counting for two conditions: first, only considering other entries in Column A that have the same Requirement name; and second, counting in order of the date/time listed in Column F. This should hold up upon sorting, because the dates in Column F are constant.

**Note:**

I don't know how you intend to use this in real-world application, but if the number appended after the last dot exceeds 9, you may wind up with sorting issues if trying to sort by the ID column itself; because as string, .10 comes before .9 (because the ASCII character "1" comes before "9"), etc. This is easy to control for by simply extending the number of digits after the final dot to accommodate the max number of digits you expect to ever have after that dot. If you think this will be an issue, leave a comment letting me know the max number you expend to be appended, and I'll make that edit to the formula to accommodate.

Comment: This answer is very thorough and helps with a few other issues I have been having Thank you! However, I have not marked this as the solution since I was looking for GAS solution. Sorry, I should have been more specific in OP.

Comment: I am not sure if I should update the OP title to include "using GAS" or create a new post. Technically your solution works if GAS is not a requirement.

Comment: @Rapscallion, I would recommend that you create a new post including "using GAS" and an explanation as to why GAS must be used for your project over an in-sheet array formula. Most often, even including "using GAS" in a title will result in array formula suggestions, because many (like me) will assume that the poster does not know that such a thing can be accomplished strictly with formulas. As it stands, I'm still not sure why GAS with onEdit would be preferable to my formula, which has the same result and auto-expands as new data is added.

Comment: To be honest you are partially correct and I did not really know it would be possible with a formula. However, I also want to leave the door open for future improvements, and a GAS solution is easier to follow and modify (for me). I will accept this solution and will at some point create a new post for a GAS solution. I really appreciate your help on this! Happy New Year!

Comment: @Rapscallion, I've been using spreadsheets since they came out. And while I do use scripts for extremely complex integrated systems, I'd say that they're not necessary for 95% of tasks within any one spreadsheet. (Though, as you imply, each person has their own view of "easy.") Glad to help get you where you want to go, at least for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] **Array  Formula Solution**

This solution uses a custom Google Apps Script Function to return the next issue id in a cell in your spreadsheet for the requirement name in the cell directly to the left of the cell containing the formula. Working example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11m-P48QFAlrYGD53Qg1w8glkAgtc4YjgFQAT4n-NHD0/edit?usp=sharing).

This function assumes that your data is structured as shown in your question, with requirement names in 1 column and issue id in column 2. For example, if your requirement IDs are in column A and your issue IDs are in column B, then you would enter `=getNextIssueNumFromArray(A2, $A$1:$B1)` into column B2 and copy that formula down column B for as many rows as you have requirement names in column A. So, when the formula reaches B10, it would be `=getNextIssueNumFromArray(A10, $A$1:$B9)`. Note that the columns do not need to be A and B, they just need to be next to each other with the requirement name on the left and the issue id on the right.

E.g.

| Requirement Name | Issue Number |
| --- | --- |
| (A1) Requirement 1 | 1.1.1.1 |
| (A2) Requirement 1 | `=getNextIssueNumFromArray(A2, $A$1:$B1)` = 1.1.1.2 |

Here is the code to implement the array formula solution

```
// the first argument, requirement name, is obtained from the cell directly to the left of this formula
// the second argument is a list of all of the requirement names and issue ids that came before the row in which this formula is pasted
// e.g. if getNextIssueNumFromArray is in cell B10, then it would be called as =getNextIssueNumFromArray(A10, $A$1:$B:9)
function getNextIssueNumFromArray(requirementName, input) {
  var requirementId = getRequirementId(requirementName);
  var max = 0;
  var searchTerm = requirementId + '.';
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i][1].indexOf(searchTerm) === -1) continue;
    issueNum = +input[i][1].replace(searchTerm, '');
    max = issueNum > max ? issueNum : max;
  }
  return requirementId + '.' + (max + 1);
}

//given a string requirement name, return a string requirement id
function getRequirementId(requirementName) {
  return '1.' + requirementName.replace('Requirement ', '') + '.1';
}
```

**Google Apps Script Solution**

*These functions are intended to be run in the GAS code editor of a Google spreadsheet*

Here are two functions that will allow you to get the maximum issue number for a given requirement id in a given spreadsheet, sheet, and column. To get the next number increment the number returned by `maxIssueForRequirement`. Working example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q4lsqf6_v8ZE-NnsAicxT33uvpKQWeb1MITG3YcCs8s/edit?usp=sharing)

```
//given a string requirement name, return a string requirement id
function getRequirementId(requirementName) {
  return '1.' + requirementName.replace('Requirement ', '') + '.1';
}

function test1() {
  Logger.log(getRequirementId('Requirement 12'));
}

test1() // returns '1.1.12'  

// given a string requirementId (e.g. 1.1.1), spreadsheet id, sheet name, and column number, return an integer max issue number with that requirement id
function maxIssueForRequirement(requirementId, ssId, sheetName, colNum) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  var s = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var r = s.getDataRange();
  var d = r.getValues();
  var max = 0;
  var searchTerm = requirementId + '.';
  var issueNum;
  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    if (d[i][colNum - 1].indexOf(searchTerm) === -1) continue;
    issueNum = +d[i][colNum -1].replace(searchTerm, '');
    max = issueNum > max ? issueNum : max;
  }
  return max;
}

function test2() {
  Logger.log(maxIssueForRequirement('1.1.1', '1Q4lsqf6_v8ZE-NnsAicxT33uvpKQWeb1MITG3YcCs8s', 'Sheet1', 2));
}

test2(); // returns 4, given data provided in OP and linked in example
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! (I honestly was not expecting an answer so soon considering it's Christmas). My ultimate goal is to auto populate the Issue_ID using onEdit(), but I am pretty sure I will be able to adapt what you provided. 
(I won't be able to test/play with it fully for a few days but I will definitely let you know if this works for me).

Comment: I have been trying to work with your GAS solution, however the Requirement ID is in no way fixed as is implied by your example (GetRequirementID is using simple concatenation instead of an actual ID lookup from the Requirement sheet). As stated in the OP I am fairly new to GAS so forgive me if I am missing something obvious that addresses this in your solution.

Comment: @Rapscallion in that case you would swap `getRequirementId` for a function that looks up the requirement id based on a given lookup value. But it looks like you're no longer looking for a GAS solution.